# Which part of my computer is broken/destroys graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure

A few days ago my graphics card broke showing weird ASCII signs after BIOS messages (text from GRUB menu displayed as random rare ASCII signs)and a screen full of quotes:

[image: ASCII]

A second graphics card showed the same result.  This second card also showed the same result afterwards in another computer otherwise working fine.

I will receive a new card and a new power supply in the next days, but I'm concerned that whatever caused the two cards to break might break the new card, as well.

Comment: the only time I have personally seen that it was caused by a blown capacitor. However the second card kind of confuses the issue. Some might blame the psu for causing capacitors to fail, but I would *expect* that voltage regulators etc would prevent that (?). Were both cards identical and purchased at the same time?

Comment: the second card was a low budget one, used because i thought the first card simply broke, but showed the exact same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're right to describe it as hardware failure if the broken card did not work in another computer after this began to occur. Unless there has been physical damage from impacts or water to the graphics card, its most likely due to damage from an overload of power - make sure that the wattage on your power supply is appropriate for your system. That said, I've never seen something like this before, so that's really just a somewhat educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply is the most likely thing to permanently damage the video card.  That said, the video card is also plugged into the motherboard, so a motherboard giving electricity to the video card could also be an issue.

I would definitely also consider replacing what you plug into the video card.  Try another video cable (which might, or might not, be attached to your monitor), and try another monitor.